# How to write binary literals in Scala?

Tags: scala, binary

Scala has direct support for using hex and octal numbers:

```
scala> 01267 + 0100
res1: Int = 759

scala> 0x12AF + 0x100
res2: Int = 5039
```

but how do you do express an integer as a binary number in Scala ?.

Comment: Note that as of 2.10, the use of a leading 0 to mean octal is deprecated.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If performance is not an issue, you can use a String and convert it to an integer.

```
val x = Integer.parseInt("01010101", 2)
```

Binary numbers aren't supported directly in part because you can easily convert from hexadecimal to binary and vice versa. To make your code clearer, you can put the binary number in a comment.

```
val x = 0x55 //01010101
```

Comment: Wow, that sucks. I don't agree with the justification that "you can easily convert from hexadecimal to binary and vice versa". If what you want is to use binary notation I think you should be able to, especially because Java supports it =(

Comment: Your recipe does not work for me `val x : Int = -2147483648` followed by `val y : Int = Integer.parseInt(x.toBinaryString, 2)` yields an exception. Notice that `x` is still a valid integer number.

Answer (score 20):

In 2.10 you can create a string interpolator for that, e.g. it's possible to write `b"0010"` to mean `2`. Using macros you can get rid of associated runtime overhead and do the conversion at compile-time. Take a look at Jason Zaugg's [macrocosm](https://github.com/retronym/macrocosm) to see it in action:

```
scala> b"101010"
res4: Int = 42

scala> b"102"
<console>:11: error: exception during macro expansion: invalid binary literal
              b"102"
              ^
```

Answer (score 9):

Using the new "implicit class" and "value class" mechanisms in 2.10, you can write something like this to add convenience methods without the overhead of object creation:

```
implicit class IntToBase( val digits:String ) extends AnyVal {
  def base(b:Int) = Integer.parseInt( digits, b )
  def b = base(2)
  def o = base(8)
  def x = base(16)
}
```

That allows you to do things like

```
"555".o  // 365 decimal
```

and no IntToBase object is ever actually created.

Comment: This doesn't handle negative numbers in two's complement: "11111111111111111111111111111111".b =>
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "11111111111111111111111111111111"

Comment: Yes, parseInt() considers a leading "-" the indicator that you mean a negative number.  The number you specified doesn't have that, so parseInt() thinks you mean the positive number, which is too large to be a 32-bit signed integer -- hence the exception.  parseInt() does not consider a 1 in the high-order bit position to be an indicator that you mean a negative number (which would be a machine-dependent interpretation anyway).

Answer (score 6):

You would need to be careful if you're converting from an integer that "looks like" binary as @agilesteel suggests. For example `0101.b` would try to convert 65 decimal to binary (initial 0 signifying octal), whereas `101.b` would try to convert 101 decimal to binary. It only really makes sense to try to convert from a String, for which there is `Integer.parseInt`, and from a number to the binary String representation, for which there is `Integer.toString(x, 2)`.

I can't think of too many use-cases for programmatic binary literals. That said, they've [made it to Java 7](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/binary-literals.html) as a number with prefix `0b`, so I'd be surprised if they didn't appear in Scala soon. Java seems to have done fine without them for 15 years though.

Comment: Java has done "fine" without unsigned chars or decent bitwise operators too. By "fine", I mean people just give up on writing stuff that needs that in Java, or else suffer cursing Java every inch of the way.

Answer (score 4):

If you are planning on using it a lot you can simulate the behavior with an implicit conversion.

```
object Extensions {
  implicit def conversion(x: Int) = new BinaryInt(x)
  class BinaryInt(x: Int) {
    def b = {
      // Conversion code like Integer.parseInt
      // as Kim suggested
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can do stuff like

```
import Extensions._
val x = 0101.b
// or
val x = 5.b
```

You have to decide for yourself, which direction the conversion should go.

Comment: Be careful: `0101` is an octal number!

Comment: It was till 2.10. See the other comments.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get a string of the binary representation of an Int you can call `4.toBinaryString`. Padding is more difficult. You'll have to do something like: `4.toBinaryString.reverse.padTo(8, "0").reverse.mkString`

Answer (score 0):

```
def _0b(row: Int): Int = {
  row.toString
    .reverse
    .split("")
    .zipWithIndex
    .map(x => (x._1.toInt, x._2))
    .filter(_._1 == 1)
    .map(x => Math.pow(2,x._2).toInt)
    .sum
}

_0b(10011001) = 153
```

Though it is limited to 32Bit Values

Answer (score 0):

More than a decade later, Scala 2.13.13 supports binary literals.

https://github.com/scala/scala/releases/tag/v2.13.13